# JavaCV: how to get descriptor's binary string

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv, image-recognition, javacv

I'm trying to use JavaCV to implement image recognition using ORB algorithm. According to some papers [[1]](https://willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/orb_final.pdf),[[2]](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/175537/files/2069.pdf), ORB keypoint descriptor is a binary string. So, how can I get this binary string after obtaining keypoints of an image?

Here is the code with which I get keypoints

```
KeyPoint keypoints = new KeyPoint();
ORB orb = new ORB(MAX_FEATURES, (float) 1.2, 8, 1, 0, 2, 5, 31);
orb.detect(originalImg, greyScaleImg, keypoints);
```

Code to get descriptor supposed to be:

```
DescriptorExtractor descriptor = orb.getDescriptorExtractor();
descriptor.compute(greyScaleImg, keypoints, descriptors);
```

As there is no documentation about descriptor functions neither javadocs. I don't know what type should be parameter descriptors and how to print the binary string. Could appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `descriptors` parameter is supposed to be a 2D-matrix `Mat` (from `org.opencv.core.Mat`):

- dimension: `NxD` where `N = number of keypoints` (row) and `D = descriptor dimension = 32` (columns),
- type: `CV_8UC1`, i.e. each matrix value is a byte (a.k.a 8-bit single-channel matrix).

Each descriptor can be represented by concatenating the 32 bytes into a byte array made of 256 bits that is why the papers refer to it as a *binary string*.

See `ORBDescriptorExtractorTest.java` for more details.

Comment: I can't understand how can I "concatenating the 32 bytes into a byte array made of 256 bits "

Comment: If want to load the i-th descriptor into a byte array you should do something like: `byte[] desc = new byte[descriptors.cols()];` then `descriptors.get(i, 0, desc);`. With it you are free to create a string (`String descStr = new String(desc);`) or manipulate it the way you want. That being said you should not have to do this since you are supposed to compare descriptors via the Hamming distance, and you can do so via `double dist = Core.norm(descA, descB, Core.NORM_HAMMING);`.

Comment: Any suggestions what should I do if opencv which I had installed doesn't contains Core module?

Comment: If your goal is to match descriptors, check if your JavaCV version provides the `DescriptorMatcher`: you may want to create one matcher with `DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING` mode and use it to match a pair of query and train descriptors.